# Changes to updated CSS file do not take effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have the following haml file in my ROR application, which I am trying to implement typography and font changes to via CSS for the portion of text under **#index_orders**.  However, when I've implemented the changes below, specifcally in the CSS file, nothing is taking effect when I refresh my development environment (localhost:3000).

Here is the haml file below with the appropriate nesting and spacing included:

index.html.haml

```
<div class="jumbotron">
%h1 <center><font color ="#c0392b"><i>Hello World!</i></font>
<center>
%br/
%h3 Some Generic Message, Woot! :)
%br/
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Sign Up</a>
```

```
#index_orders
  - @orders.each do |order|
      %h3= link_to order.date.strftime("%A %B %d, %Y"), order
      %h4= order.name
```

Now here is the select portion of the application CSS file with the relevant code:

application.css.scss

```
#index_orders {
    h2 {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-weight: 100;
            a {
               color: white;
            }
        }
    }
```

Why aren't the font color/typography changes taking effect?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styling rule is only targeting the `h2` element. As there is not an `h2` element in your index.html.haml, you will not see the anticipated visual changes.

To see the styling rule applied, change the `h2` selector in application.css.scss to target the desired `h1` or `h3` element.

For example,

```
#index_orders {
    h3 {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-weight: 100;
            a {
               color: white;
            }
        }
    }
```